# Difference between HTTPS and SSL

Tags: security, ssl, https, communication, communication-protocol

What is the difference between HTTPS and SSL? I read about them and found following:

- **HTTPS**: HTTPS is a combination of HTTP with SSL/TLS. It means that HTTPS is basically HTTP connection which is delivering the data secured using SSL/TLS.
- **SSL**: SSL is a secure protocol that works on the top of HTTP to provide security. That means SSL encrypted data will be routed using protocols like HTTP for communication.

I am wondering where is the difference between these two? Or both are identical?

Comment: You may be interested in this similar question: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5126/2435

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The explanation of SSL that you've found is wrong.

SSL (Secure Socket Layer) or [TLS (Transport Layer Security)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) works on top of the [transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer), in your examples [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). TLS can be used for more or less any protocol, HTTPS is just one common instance of it.

HTTP is an [application layer protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Layer).

In regular, non-encrypted HTTP, the protocol stack can look like this:

- [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)
- [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)
- [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol)
- [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)

When using HTTPS, the stack looks like this:

- HTTP
- **TLS (SSL)**
- TCP
- IP
- Ethernet

Comment: Thanks Anders. So, it means that the HTTPS and SSL(when HTTP is used as Transport layer protocol) are same?

Comment: Not really, HTTP is an application protocol. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: "HTTPS is just on common **instance** of it" really helped solidify this for me!

Comment: For more depth on certificates and weakness of HTTPS, see the SO answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856209/difference-between-https-protocol-and-ssl-certificate?rq=1

Answer (score 43):

HTTPS runs over SSL (as it's name suggests, HTTP-over-SSL), not SSL over HTTP. First SSL session is established, then all HTTP data are wrapped into secured SSL packets before sending and after receiving.

Comment: I got it. I didn't frame my query properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

**SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)** is a standard security technology to create an encrypted link between a server and a client. This link ensures that all data passed between the server and the client remain private and secure.
It was designed to support protocols such as FTP, HTTP, TELNET.

**Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS)** or “HTTP Secure,” is an application specific implementation that is a combination of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) with the SSL/TLS. HTTPS is used to provide encrypted communication and secure identification of a server, so that no middle man can intercept the data easily.

As everything in HTTP is in plain text `(or encoded)` , it is used with SSL/TLS to encrypt it.

**Found this link which explains SSL, TLS, HTTPS :
http://nexsniper.blogspot.com/2017/11/what-is-ssl-tls-and-https.html**

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was really helpful!